# Element Can't Be Found, Substitute Text Instead

Tags: python, selenium

Sometimes in the page I'm scraping, "price" xpath cannot be found. I would like to substitute the text "No pricing info available" when it can't find the "price" xpath element, instead of it ending in an error. I'm sure it has something to do with "try and except" but not sure how to write it. Thanks!

UPDATED IN LAST CODE BLOCK

```
#finds titles
deal_title = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='dealTitle']/span")
titles = []
for title in deal_title:
    titles.append(title.text)

#finds links
deal_link = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-row dealDetailContainer']/div/a[@id='dealTitle']")
links = []
for link in deal_link:
    links.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

#finds images
deal_image = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='dealImage']/div/div/div/img")
images = []
for image in deal_image:
    images.append(image.get_attribute('src'))

#finds prices (if present)    
deal_price = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-row priceBlock unitLineHeight']/span")
prices = []
for price in deal_price:
    prices.append(price.text)

#writes to html
for title, link, image, price in zip(titles, links, images, prices):
    f.write("<tr class='border'><td class='image'>" + "<img src=" + image + "></td>" + "<td class='title'><a href=" + link + '>'">" + title + "</a></td><td class='price'>" + price + "</td></tr>")
```

UPDATE: So I've updated the code to be like this so the value of price will have a place holder instead of passing through it, which causes a mismatch in (title, link, image, price) when writing to file. Any ideas on how to do this correctly so when it writes, the text "PRINT/WRITE THIS TEXT INSTEAD OF PASSING" will be written to file?

```
#finds titles
deal_title = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='dealTitle']/span")
titles = []
for title in deal_title:
    titles.append(title.text)

#finds links
deal_link = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-row dealDetailContainer']/div/a[@id='dealTitle']")
links = []
for link in deal_link:
    links.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

#finds images
deal_image = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='dealImage']/div/div/div/img")
images = []
for image in deal_image:
    images.append(image.get_attribute('src'))

try:

    deal_price = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-row priceBlock unitLineHeight']/span")
    prices = []
    for price in deal_price:
        prices.append(price.text)

except NoSuchElementException:
    price = ("PRINT/WRITE THIS TEXT INSTEAD OF PASSING")

#writes to html
for title, link, image, price in zip(titles, links, images, prices):
    f.write("<tr class='border'><td class='image'>" + "<img src=" + image + "></td>" + "<td class='title'><a href=" + link + '>'">" + title + "</a></td><td class='price'>" + price + "</td></tr>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `deal_price`before trying to iterate over it.

```
deal_price = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-row priceBlock unitLineHeight']/span")

# did we find any prices?
if deal_price:
    prices = []
    for price in deal_price:
        prices.append(price.text)

else:
    # handle missing prices...
```

Comment: Thanks John, if it can't find the xpath value of "deal_price" then the script errors out. I need to put in a check to do something else if it can't find the deal_price xpath.

Answer (score 0):

When the **price** cannot be found to substitute with the text **Price Unavailable** you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  browser=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  browser.get("https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_ftr_s-4_bedf_page_10?gb_f_deals1=enforcedCategories:2972638011,dealStates:AVAILABLE%252CWAITLIST%252CWAITLISTFULL,includedAccessTypes:,page:10,sortOrder:BY_SCORE,dealsPerPage:32&pf_rd_p=afc45143-5c9c-4b30-8d5c-d838e760bedf&pf_rd_s=slot-4&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=ZDV4YBQJFDVR3PAY4ZBS&ie=UTF8")
  #finds images
  deal_image = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-row dealContainer dealTile']//div[@class='a-row layer']/img")
  images = []
  prices = []
  for image in deal_image:
      images.append(image.get_attribute('src'))
      #finds relevant prices
      try :
          deal_price = image.find_element_by_xpath("./following::div[2]//div[@class='a-row a-spacing-mini'][2]/div[@class='a-row priceBlock unitLineHeight']/span")
          prices.append(deal_price.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
      except NoSuchElementException:
          prices.append("Price Unavailable") 

  #print the information
  for image, price in zip(images, prices):
      print(image, price)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/5102g01O1nL._AA210_.jpg $19.60
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51N2rdMSh0L._AA210_.jpg $22.99 - $24.99
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31XsztnbNGL._AA210_.jpg $123.20 - $133.63
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31fNbfTW35L._AA210_.jpg $241.21 - $267.00
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41fuZZwdruL._AA210_.jpg $41.24
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51hC7rJT-VL._AA210_.jpg $39.95
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41nziezVczL._AA210_.jpg Price Unavailable
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41OeZ0KTE8L._AA210_.jpg Price Unavailable
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41QVEcJWLeL._AA210_.jpg Price Unavailable
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51XqV4DKV%2BL._AA210_.jpg $92.24
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31-QDRkNbhL._AA210_.jpg $15.80
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51MQu5v%2BQJL._AA210_.jpg $17.41
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/316KunRLRZL._AA210_.jpg Price Unavailable
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/512s5ZrjoFL._AA210_.jpg $51.99
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51A8Nfvf8eL._AA210_.jpg $8.30
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51aDac6YN5L._AA210_.jpg $18.53
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/418aN7ErLJL._AA210_.jpg $179.30
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31SQON%2BiOBL._AA210_.jpg $9.75
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/519hxsMZlTL._AA210_.jpg $38.99
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/515keAWwYYL._AA210_.jpg $7.97
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31aNppsuZEL._AA210_.jpg $9.49
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/4104Jm-d3IL._AA210_.jpg $15.35
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31abuAZRuqL._AA210_.jpg Price Unavailable
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51en-FhtpbL._AA210_.jpg Price Unavailable
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41qLIdqYXjL._AA210_.jpg Price Unavailable
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41bbblEeCWL._AA210_.jpg Price Unavailable
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/316fGtNzmZL._AA210_.jpg $12.71
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51OtBDMnPtL._AA210_.jpg $55.86
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51IwkmtXKhL._AA210_.jpg $22.53
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41fsdPNN71L._AA210_.jpg $23.31
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41vgtpZ5H3L._AA210_.jpg $21.01
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41vXJ9fvcIL._AA210_.jpg $88.99
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41qzYct%2BPNL._AA210_.jpg Price Unavailable
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51K4hWy5wBL._AA210_.jpg Price Unavailable
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51oxPj3Fz8L._AA210_.jpg Price Unavailable
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51rCyK90S2L._AA210_.jpg Price Unavailable
  ```
- Link:

  ```
  https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_ftr_s-4_bedf_page_10?gb_f_deals1=enforcedCategories:2972638011,dealStates:AVAILABLE%252CWAITLIST%252CWAITLISTFULL,includedAccessTypes:,page:10,sortOrder:BY_SCORE,dealsPerPage:32&pf_rd_p=afc45143-5c9c-4b30-8d5c-d838e760bedf&pf_rd_s=slot-4&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=ZDV4YBQJFDVR3PAY4ZBS&ie=UTF8
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Price_Unavailable]